# How to make the highlight color of an IconButton appear over parent widget?

Tags: flutter

When I set the color of a Container that holds an IconButton, I find that highlight color of the IconButton is hidden by the color of the container.  Here's what I mean:

[image]

How can ensure that the blue circle appears *above* the red square?

Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new MyDemo()));
}

class MyDemo extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container(
          width: 60.0,
          height: 60.0,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: new IconButton(
            highlightColor: Colors.blue,
            icon: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo), onPressed: ()=>{},),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

InkSplash occurs on the closest ancestor [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) widget.

You can get that widget using `Material.of(context)` which provides a few helpers for InkSplashes.

In your case, it's `InkResponse` instantiated by [`IconButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) which provoke the Splash effect.
But the targeted [`Material`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Material-class.html) widget is instantiated by `Scaffold`. Which is an ancestor of your background. Therefore the background paints above your InkSplash.

To solve this problem you'd have to introduce a new `Material` instance between your background and your `IconButton`.

Which leads to :

[image]

Guh, we solved the problem. But now it's cropped !
Let's continue.

The easiest option would be to split your rendering in two branches. One for the background, and one for the UI. Something similar should do the trick :

```
return new Scaffold(
  body: new Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: <Widget>[
      new Center(
        child: new Container(
          height: 60.0,
          width: 60.0,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
      new Material(
        type: MaterialType.transparency,
        child: new IconButton(
          highlightColor: Colors.blue,
          icon: new Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
          onPressed: () => {},
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
 Material(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    shape: CircleBorder(),
    clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
    child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      iconSize: 30,
      color: Colors.white,
      onPressed: () {

      },
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try CircleAvatar.

```
CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, Notifications.id);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.bell),),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html#material.IconButton.2):

> It's easy enough to create an icon button with a filled background using the Ink widget. The Ink widget renders a decoration on the underlying Material along with the splash and highlight InkResponse contributed by descendant widgets.

Just replace your Container by an Ink:

```
Ink(
      width: 60.0,
      height: 60.0,
      color: Colors.red,
      child: IconButton(
        highlightColor: Colors.blue,
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        onPressed: () => {},
      ),
    ),
```

[image]