# InkWell not working with a background image

Tags: dart, flutter

I am building my first Flutter app and I would like to create a simple layout: a background image and a translucent Material Button on top of it.

My Widget tree is pretty simple, but the InkWell / Ripple is not visible. Why do I have this behaviour ?

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage("res/imgs/splashscreen_bg.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ))),
          new Center(
              child: new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {}, child: new Text("Hello world")))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Without the background image, the InkWell is working. 
What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the highlight color of an IconButton appear over parent widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46681318/how-to-make-the-highlight-color-of-an-iconbutton-appear-over-parent-widget)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a few researches, I have found this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/3782

And if I change the Widget content with this new tree, it now works:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage("res/imgs/splashscreen_bg.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ))),
          new Material(
            type: MaterialType.transparency,
          child: new FlatButton(...),
          )
        ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was a recent update to support this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/13900. I'm not sure if it has made its way to alpha yet, but it should solve your issue.